# EntityManager em.getTransaction().begin() locks thread

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, deadlock, entitymanager

My question is, if the method "begin()" is capable of lock a thread further than the "timeout" config in the persistence.xml.

Here is a snippet:

```
@Inject EntityManager em;
@Inject ContextControl ctxCtrl;
String fileType;
String fileName;
String hash;
BufferedReader reader = null;

public void run(File f, String fileType, String hash) throws ProcessorException, IOException{    
        this.fileType = fileType;        
        this.hash= hash;
        this.fileName = f.getName();

        try { 
          ctxCtrl.startContext(RequestScoped.class);
          em.getTransaction().begin();
          reader = openReader(f);

          //rest of the code...

         em.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
          try{ //for database breakdown purpose
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
          }catch(Exception e2){
            logger.error(e2.getMessage(), e2);
            throw new ProcessorException();
        }      
        throw new ProcessorException();      
    }finally{
      reader.close();
      ctxCtrl.stopContext(RequestScoped.class);   
    }
```

"run" method is executed inside a loop. This method is executed serially, there is no possible concurrency.
Now, the thing is that the thread stops randomly at line "em.getTransaction().begin();", with no exception. And since this is a critical area, all the application is stopped and the lock is never released.

The only thing I can think of is the "begin()" method getting stuck somehow, but not in an exception way, but rather in a lock way (since no exception is caught). 
I wasn't able to recreate the issue, I can only say that the issue has nothing to do with the file. Also, this is happening in production, so I can't debug the application other than check some logs

thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I use Deltaspike to provide the CDI. Entitymanager it's injected anytime it's needed. It's created like this:

**CLASS ENTITYMANAGER FACTORY PRODUCER**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerFactoryProducer {
  @Inject Logger logger;

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public EntityManagerFactory create() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
      props.load(new FileInputStream("cfg/connection.properties"));
    } catch (Exception e) {      
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("scgach",props);
  }

  public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    factory.close();
  }
}
```

**CLASS ENTITYMANAGER PRODUCER**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Disposes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {

  @Inject EntityManagerFactory emf;

  @Produces @RequestScoped
  public EntityManager create() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
  }

  public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
    if(em.isOpen())
      em.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your transaction isolation settings?

Comment: @Kayaman <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="1" />

Comment: Have you checked the database and connection pool to see that there's nothing shady going on?

Comment: @Kayaman this is happening in production, where I don't have access to. We use hibernate+c3p0 and MS SQL server 2008

Comment: Well contact your server people and ask them about it.